# Magento Category Product Count issues

Tags: product, category

Good days everyone,

i am using the default Magento web page template and i have some issues with categories product count.

1) Problem 1

Under the Default Category (**Manage Category**),

I created a root category named **Women** and sub category of **Women** named **Dress**. I added a product named **BlackDress** and categorize on **Women** / **Dress**.

Under **Manage Category** section --> **Women** (0) --> **Dress**(1), the product count of all items in **Women** category is shown 0 which is not true. (I have one item on women subdirectory)

2) Problem 2

By default, when i clicked on the **Women** Menu, there is 1 dropdown menu --> **Dress**. When i clicked **Dress** menu --> Its display the item **BlackDress** but i received the following problem after clicking View All Women menu.

BROWSE BY

CATEGORY
**Dress** (0)

Can anyone professional advise on this?

Comment: which magento version you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make all category anchor(is_anchor=1) is  yes ,from design of tab category